# ASM (at&t system V 32bit XOR)

Tags: assembly, xor

i was trying to make a simple little password program (to further expand my knowledge) and i just can't get it to work. the problem is even though i enter the correct password it will not jump to the label "good".

my way of validating the password is to xor the built in password with the user submitted one and if it returns 0 that means they are the same. (because anything xor'd by itself is 0)

so my mistake is most likely within the cmpl and je commands or within my xoring itself. any help would be nice i simply can't find my mistake.

```
.section .data

hmm:
.ascii "Enter the password\n\0"

password:
.ascii "abgirl"

success:
.ascii "Password is right\n\0"

bad:
.ascii "password is wrong\n\0"

.section .bss

.equ buffer_size, 500

.lcomm buffer_data, buffer_size

.section .text

.global _start

_start:

pushl $hmm
call printf                      #print $hmm

movl $0, %ebx
movl $buffer_data, %ecx
movl $buffer_size, %edx
movl $3, %eax
int $0x80                        #get user input

movl $password, %eax
xorl $buffer_data, %eax          #xor the passwords (value stored in eax)

cmpl $0, %eax                    #compare
je good                          #jump if equal

pushl $bad
call printf                      #print bad pass if not equal
jmp end                          #jump to exit

good:
pushl $success
call printf                      #print $success

end:
movl $0, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80                        #cleanup and exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the comparison.

```
movl $password, %eax
xorl $buffer_data, %eax
```

The dollar signs mean you are working with the addresses of the variables, not the contents. Since the password and buffer are at different locations, the comparison will always be false. What you want is to compare the character in each position of the password and buffer. To do this, you will need to know how long the password is.

```
password:
.ascii "abgirl\0"
.set password_len, . - password
```

Notice that I also added a null byte to your password, so that the comparison will fail if the input password is longer. Now, you need to change your comparison to check each byte.

```
    movl $password, %ebx
    movl $buffer_data, %edx
    movl $password_len, %ecx
0:
    movb (%ebx), %al
    xorb (%edx), %al
    jnz bad
    inc %ebx
    inc %edx       # Go to next byte
    dec %ecx
    jnz 0b
    jmp good
```

Comment: thanks so much i got it working with your help. although is there a way to xor the entire password at once because i've heard of timed brute forcing attacks ex: if password was "bruce" you can try "a" takes 0.2ms try "b" takes 0.4ms so you know b is in the pass then try all up to "r" (each taking 0.4ms) then and it takes 0.6ms so you know r is part of it and so on (figurative times)

Comment: No, there isn't. You could compare longs while there are 4 bytes left, which would mean the timing would only change if the first 4 characters are correct. You could also try to program it so that it checks each character, even if the first is wrong.